# Your version of snapd is outdated

Tags: https, debian, certbot

I am trying to get and install some https certificates for apache on Debian 10 by following this: https://certbot.eff.org/lets-encrypt/debianbuster-apache

Everything is going fine until step 7: `sudo certbot --apache`:

```
An error occurred while fetching Certbot snap plugins: your version of snapd is outdated.
Please run "sudo snap install core; sudo snap refresh core" in your terminal and try again.
An unexpected error occurred:
requests.exceptions.HTTPError: 404 Client Error: Not Found for url: http://snapd/v2/connections?snap=certbot&interface=content
Please see the logfile '/tmp/tmp5xjbr23v/log' for more details.
```

When I run `sudo snap install core; sudo snap refresh core`:

```
snap "core" is already installed, see 'snap help refresh'
error: cannot refresh "core": refreshing disabled snap "core" not supported
```

Looking at the log (`/tmp/tmp5xjbr23v/log`):

```
2020-11-04 00:26:04,950:DEBUG:urllib3.connectionpool:http://localhost:None "GET /v2/connections?snap=certbot&interface=content HTTP/1.1" 404 88
2020-11-04 00:26:04,951:ERROR:certbot._internal.snap_config:An error occurred while fetching Certbot snap plugins: your version of snapd is outdated.
2020-11-04 00:26:04,951:ERROR:certbot._internal.snap_config:Please run "sudo snap install core; sudo snap refresh core" in your terminal and try again.
2020-11-04 00:26:04,951:DEBUG:certbot._internal.log:Exiting abnormally:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/snap/certbot/652/bin/certbot", line 8, in <module>
    sys.exit(main())
  File "/snap/certbot/652/lib/python3.8/site-packages/certbot/main.py", line 15, in main
    return internal_main.main(cli_args)
  File "/snap/certbot/652/lib/python3.8/site-packages/certbot/_internal/main.py", line 1330, in main
    cli_args = snap_config.prepare_env(cli_args)
  File "/snap/certbot/652/lib/python3.8/site-packages/certbot/_internal/snap_config.py", line 67, in prepare_env
    raise e
  File "/snap/certbot/652/lib/python3.8/site-packages/certbot/_internal/snap_config.py", line 57, in prepare_env
    response.raise_for_status()
  File "/snap/certbot/652/lib/python3.8/site-packages/requests/models.py", line 941, in raise_for_status
    raise HTTPError(http_error_msg, response=self)
requests.exceptions.HTTPError: 404 Client Error: Not Found for url: http://snapd/v2/connections?snap=certbot&interface=content
2020-11-04 00:26:04,951:ERROR:certbot._internal.log:An unexpected error occurred:
2020-11-04 00:26:04,951:ERROR:certbot._internal.log:requests.exceptions.HTTPError: 404 Client Error: Not Found for url: http://snapd/v2/connections?snap=certbot&interface=content
```

Here more details about the version that might be useful `sudo snap version`:

```
snap    2.37.4-1+b1
snapd   2.37.4-1+b1
series  16
debian  10
kernel  4.19.0-11-cloud-amd64
```

I tried to reinstall snapd (https://snapcraft.io/docs/installing-snap-on-debian) using the last version but still having the same..
Do you guys know what is wrong with my setup and how to fix that?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well I fixed this using:
`sudo snap remove core`
`sudo snap install core`

And now I have:

```
snap    2.47.1
snapd   2.47.1
```

I guess I was too tired.

Comment: `> sudo snap remove core
error: cannot remove "core": snap "core" is not removable`
Sorry, how did you do?